# How can I store columns of a text in an array with which I can then make calculations?

Tags: java, arrays, list, data-structures

community,
I am currently stuck on a homework assignment which requires me to read a text file and then make further calculations with it, my questions are now.
How do I read a text file and store the columns in several arrays to make further calculations?
I have written a piece of code which already reads the file, but doesn't seem to store the columns in arrays as I keep getting "ArrayOutOfBoundsException".

I have already tried the given code below, which doesn't give me what I need.
Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that was able to solve the problem.
The columns are separated by Tabs.
This is what the table looks like

Date      Open     High      Low       Close       Volume

29.12.2017 12.980,09 12980.74 12.911,773 12.917.64  1.905.806.208
....
....
....
and so on

```java
try {
  ArrayList < String > KursDaten = new ArrayList<String>();
  String Zeile = null;
  while ((Zeile = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Zeile = Zeile.replaceAll("\u0000", "");
    Zeile = Zeile.replaceAll("�", "");
    String[] columns = in.readLine().split(" ");
    columns = in.readLine().split("\t");
    String data = columns[columns.length - 1];
    KursDaten.add(data);
    out.println(Zeile);
  }
  int size = KursDaten.size();
  out.println(KursDaten.size());
  String[] arr1 = new String[size];
  String[] arr2 = new String[size];
  String[] arr3 = new String[size];
  String[] arr4 = new String[size];
  String[] arr5 = new String[size];
  String[] arr6 = new String[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String[] temp = KursDaten.get(i).split("\t\t");
    temp = KursDaten.get(i).split("\t");
    arr1[i] = temp[0];
    arr2[i] = temp[1];
    arr3[i] = temp[2];
    arr4[i] = temp[3];
    arr5[i] = temp[4];
    arr6[i] = temp[5];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
  }
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {

}
```

I expect the columns of the list to be stored in the different arrays, with which I then can make further calculations as needed.

Comment: I did not quite understand your input format but what you should do it read data from a file line by line in a `String` and parse it based on __,__ in an array.

Comment: Suppose that when you made the split `KursDaten.get(i).split("\t");` it returns you an array with length less than 5. 
Btw when you do `temp          = KursDaten.get(i).split("\t");` you overwrite the 
`String[] temp = KursDaten.get(i).split("\t\t");` results

Comment: empty catch (NullPointerException e) is NOT A GOOD IDEA. NullPointer is mistake in the code. You want to know about it, not hide it. just not catch it -let it propagate and crash program, then fix the root cause.

Comment: You seem to be guessing wildly without really knowing what you are doing. Do you really need to do `replaceAll` and why do a split on " " before doing a, supposedly correct, split on  tab? Then you select only the last item in `columns` when the whole `columns` array contains your data to work with. If you fix this first part of your code and declare your ArrayList correctly you will not get an exception.

Comment: Thank you for all the speedy answers, if the code seems messy I do apologise, I am just starting out on coding 5th week in! I have so far cleaned up the code and got rid of my unnecessary split commands, which has already helped correctly formatting the output. As soon as I set all the elements in the ArrayList and find a solution I will post it here! Thanks again for your time and speedy answers!